# inheritance from queue C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, queue, polymorphism

I had to use fixed size queue so I designed a class like this:

```
Result VehicleParcelQueue::push_back(Parcel* pParcel){
    if (size() >= 5) return FAILURE;
    else{
        queue<Parcel*>::push_back(pParcel);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Parcel is a class I implemented elsewhere.

but I'm getting:

> error: 'push_back' is not a member of 'std::queue'

what's the problem, I thought push_back should be recognized in the scope of the derived class.

Comment: Try `push`. And have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::queue` has `push` method. `push_back` is defined for classes which are meant to work as a stack e.g. `std::vector`.